# Can PAGELATCH Waits cause increase in SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, aws

We have a high concurrency web server application on which we have some amount of `PAGELATCH_UP` & `PAGELATCH_SH` Waits due to tempdb contention. But recently we have noticed the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` Waits also going up.

Could the `PAGELATCH` Waits cause the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` Wait to go up?

Also, the web server application and sql server are hosted on the same AWS cloud server.

Comment: SOS_SCHEDULER_WAIT is *not* a wait actually. It just shows SQL server yielded the thread after it has exhausted its 4ms quantum and goes back to bottom of runnable queue. You should focus on optimizing tempdb and may be putting it on faster drive if your app uses it a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could the PAGELATCH Waits cause the SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD Wait to go up?

No.

SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait time is spend waiting on an available scheduler (CPU).  After any *other* resource wait, a session will accumulate Signal Wait Time while waiting for an available scheduler.  The Signal Wait Time is tracked along with the previous wait, and included in the reported wait_time, but broken out in the signal_wait_time column in the [Instance Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Session Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Wait Stats DMVs.

So there may be a relationship between the two waits, but it's not that the PAGELATCH causes the SOS_SCHEDULER_YEILD.  Check the signal_wait_time on the PAGELATCH wait.  If the signal_wait_time is a significant proportion of the wait_time, then the PAGELATCH waits are really CPU waits.

Note that when a session is waiting for a page latch, the session that currently owns the page latch may *itself* be waiting for CPU, so some of the non-signal wait time may also be related to CPU waits.

Put another way, excessive CPU use (or insuffient CPU resources) can cause both SOS_SCHEDULER_YEILD waits and cause other short waits to drag out as no scheduler is available at the end of the resource wait.

Comment: Ok, My Wait time now in seconds is 5236.31,  and Signal Time is 5234.50. So I guess it is actually waiting on CPU resources. The server is 64 CPU hosted in AWS, and sometimes runs the exact same test without issue. But sometimes gives bad response times. This is what is confusing!

Comment: Would continued SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits cause CPU to go up?

Comment: SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits are a _symptom_ of high CPU use, not a _cause_.